# Duplicate an auto incremented field and have the same values in the new one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with an Auto incremented field ID and I want to duplicate this column as a ID2 String for exemple but I want it to be updated each time the Id is auto incremented . I know this approch is very specific and a bit ugly but is there a way to acheive this .

exemple : starting data base .

```
ID       Title          
1       titl_14  
...  
19       titl_13    
561     titl_1     
671     titl_1      
1765    titl_1      
1834    titl_1      
1909    titl_1      
1910    titl_1
```

disered result :

```
ID       Title    ID2(varchar)      
1       titl_14    1
...               ...
19       titl_13    19
561     titl_1     561
671     titl_1     671
1765    titl_1    1765
1834    titl_1    1834 
1909    titl_1    1909 
1910    titl_1    1910
```

and when inserting a new data both ID & ID2 would be 1911 automaticly .

Thanks you in advance

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Why would you want two generated identity columns?

Comment: Does Oracle even do Auto increment? Admittedly we're stuck on 10g but that uses sequences.

Comment: Well I need to implement a function which need the field as a String but my whole code uses it as a an int and since a converter would work but this will lead to a huge refactoring , I agree this is ugly as hell .

Comment: So pass the id to the function wrapped in a TO_CHAR()? Not much factoring required there.

Comment: Create a view with `SELECT source.*, TO_CHAR(id) AS id2 FROM source`?

Comment: @MatBailie , I did this to copy all of the column but when there is a new id genreted , the id2 wont be updated

Comment: @Gengetsu - What?  The `id2` column would be recalculated every time the view is referenced...  I think that there is a terminology issue here and what you are saying is being understood differently from what you mean.  I recommend you edit your question to include an example of what you want, using dummy data, to demonstrate *(rather than describe)* the behaviour you want...

Comment: @MatBailie done this is the general idea of what I want to do .

Comment: @Gengetsu - If `ID` is already auto-incrementing then the VIEW would do exactly that...  Why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: @MatBailie it works thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 12C, you can create a generated column:

```
alter table t add id_str as (to_char(id));
```

In earlier versions, you can use a view for pretty much the same effect.

If you really want to use up storage space and take a hit on performance, you can also add the column directly into the table and use a trigger to set the value.